# JS Binding object function call to itself

Tags: javascript

I created an object with a function that refers to a property of itself using the 'this' keyword.

If I call it normally, it works fine. But if I call pass it as an argument in a forEach function it doesn't work unless I bind it to itself.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Here is an example:

```
var foobar = {

    foo : function (number) {
       this.bar();
    },

    bar : function () {
        return "string"
    }
};

foobar.foo(0);

[1,2,3].forEach(foobar.foo); //won't work

[1,2,3].forEach(foobar.foo.bind(foobar)); //works
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q29yatc2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[@Christos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913124/christos) has provided [a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27963908/1249581) of why it happens. However, answering your question, *the more elegant solution* will be passing `foobar` as [`thisArg` of `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters):

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(foobar.foo, foobar);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description) says:

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `forEach`, it will be passed to
>   callback when invoked, for use as its `this` value. Otherwise, the
>   value `undefined` will be passed for use as its `this` value.
>   The `this` value ultimately observable by callback is determined
>   according to [the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/q29yatc2/4/

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a more elegant solution?

I don't think that there is a more elegant solution.

Why this is happening?

This happens due to the change in the `context`.

This `forEach(foobar.foo)` doesn't make `this`  to refer to the foobar's instance.

On the other hand calling the `bind` method you set explicitly where the `this` would point
and this will point to foobar's instance.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the
>   same function body (internal call property in ECMAScript 5 terms) as
>   the function it is being called on (the bound function's target
>   function) **with the this value bound to the first argument of bind()**,
>   **which cannot be overridden**. bind() also accepts leading default
>   arguments to provide to the target function when the bound function is
>   called. A bound function may also be constructed using the new
>   operator: doing so acts as though the target function had instead been
>   constructed. The provided this value is ignored, while prepended
>   arguments are provided to the emulated function.

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks for your comment ! I edited my answer correspondingly.